# Errors while using readr, write_csv

Tags: r, readr

Firstly,

I'm unable to use write_csv() function. I get the below error

> Error in function_list[k] : could not find function
>   "write_csv"

I've readr pacakge installed which gives the following warning:

> Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :    cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No
>   such file or directory In addition: Warning message: package ‘readr’
>   was built under R version 3.3.3  Error: package or namespace load
>   failed for ‘readr’

Second,

when I'm trying to read a .csv or excel file I get the below error

```
c <- read_excel("C:/Users/kishore/Desktop/c.xlsx")
```

> Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :    cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No
>   such file or directory

```
View(c)
```

> Error in View : object 'c' not found

I'm not sure what is the issue please advise

Comment: You can't just give us your errors, we also have to see your code. In the dark, I might guess that you did not set the correct working directory, but without your code I can't be sure.

Comment: What does `find.package("rlang")` tell you?

Comment: So... `install.packages("rlang", "C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")`?

Comment: try to reinstall readr. Something is off with your setup.

Comment: @lukeA, 
that solved the "rlang" issue, when I tried to import the .csv file it was giving an error for "tibble" so tried to install it which let to the following 
>install.packages("tibble", "C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/tibble_1.3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 674006 bytes (658 KB)
downloaded 658 KB
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\kishore\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyIExDn\downloaded_packages

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
2: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: @sinQueso, I had been doing that all day long but throws an error:
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/tibble/R/tibble.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘readr’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
2: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’

Comment: @kishore Does `.libPaths()` point to your directory first? Maybe uninstall and reinstall? Hard to tell and very cryptic. (Putting your tries in the comment section instead of adding it to your post and providing unspecific "giving an error"s does not make it easier btw.)

Comment: I did something like copying the installation files to the folder where R packages are saved and it worked, 
    .libPaths() is showing the path
>[1] "C:/Users/kishore/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library" 

apologies for not correctly formatting my posts.

Comment: thank you for all the help here.

Answer (score 0):

PS: I know that the issue has been resolved. I just want to point you to another solution.

If you have problems with `readr` package, try using the base functions like `read.csv` and `write.csv` from `utils` package. You dont have to install any new packages.

**Example**

```
#Reading a csv
#row.names tells that the 1st row contains the headers
df <- read.csv('/Users/Desktop/sample.csv', row.names=1)

#Writing into a csv
#row.names tells that the 1st row contains the column names
write.csv(df, '/Users/Desktop/sample_copy.csv', row.names=T)
```